# Is it possible to make a hardcoding with the help of the command objcopy

Tags: c, linux, linker, objdump, objcopy

I'm working on Linux and I've just heard that there was a command `objcopy`, I've found the relative command on my x86_64 PC: `x86_64-linux-gnu-objcopy`.

With its help, I can convert a file into an obj file: `x86_64-linux-gnu-objcopy -I binary -O elf64-x86-64 custom.config custom.config.o`

The file `custom.config` is a human-readable file. It contains two lines:

```
name titi
password 123
```

Now I can execute `objdump -x -s custom.config.o` to check its information.

```
custom.config.o:     file format elf64-little
custom.config.o
architecture: UNKNOWN!, flags 0x00000010:
HAS_SYMS
start address 0x0000000000000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .data         00000017  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary_custom_config_start
0000000000000017 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary_custom_config_end
0000000000000017 g       *ABS*  0000000000000000 _binary_custom_config_size


Contents of section .data:
 0000 6e616d65 20746974 690a7061 7373776f  name titi.passwo
 0010 72642031 32330a                      rd 123.
```

As all we know, we can open, read or write a file, such as `custom.config` in any C/C++ project. Now, I'm thinking if it's possible to use this obj file `custom.config.o` immediately in a C/C++ project. For example, is it possible to read the content of the file `custom.config.o` immediately without calling the I/O functions, such as `open`, `read` or `write`. If possible, I think this might become some kind of hardcoding style and avoid calling the I/O functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I tried this on Win10 with MinGW (MinGW-W64 project, GCC 8.1.0), this should work for you with only minor adaptions.

As you see from the info `objdump` gave you, the file's contents is placed in the `.data` section that is the common section for non-constant variables.

And some symbols were defined for it. You can declare these symbols in your C source.

The absolute value `_binary_custom_config_size` is special, because it is marked `*ABS*`. Currently I know no other way to obtain its value than to declare a variable of any type and take its address.

This is my `show_config.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern const char _binary_custom_config_start[];
extern const char _binary_custom_config_size;

int main(void) {
  size_t size = (size_t)&_binary_custom_config_size;
  char config[size + 1];
  strncpy(config, _binary_custom_config_start, size);
  config[size] = '\0';
  printf("config = \"%s\"\n", config);
  return 0;
}
```

Because the "binary" file (actually a text) has no final `'\0'` character, you need to append one to get a correctly terminated C string.

You could as well declare `_binary_custom_config_end` and use it to calculate the size, or as a limit.

Building everything goes like this (I used the `-g` option to debug):

```
$ objcopy -I binary -O elf64-x86-64 -B i386 custom.config custom.config.o
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g show_config.c custom.config.o -o show_config
```

And the output shows the success:

```
$ show_config.exe
config = "name titi
password 123"
```

If you need the file's contents in another section, you will add the option to rename the section to `objcopy`'s call. Add any flag you need, the example shows `.rodata` that is used for read-only data:

`--rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents`